# jQuery EasyUI dialog element sizing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm playing around with jQuery EasyUI for the first time.  I'm trying to figure out how, if it's possible, to change the label and input size/properties in a dialog box?  Basically I would like to make the input boxes a bit larger but I can't figure out how to change these at all.

```
<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:500px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px"
        closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
    <div class="ftitle">Prospect Information</div>
    <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Prospect Name:</label>
            <input name="Name" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Phone:</label>
            <input name="Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input name="Email" class="easyui-validatebox" validType="email">
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Received Datetime:</label>
            <input name="rcvd_datetime" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on top of the page:

```
<style>
    label {
        width: 200px;
    }
    input {
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

or add the style-attribute in each tag, like this if you want to differ each element individualy:

```
<div class="fitem">
    <label style="width: 200px;">Phone:</label>
    <input name="Phone" style="height: 30px;">
</div>
```